Vimeo APi, disable fast forward through the video
I am uploading a video through vimeo API, i want to make sure that the user can't fast forward through the video and watch all of it. How can i do that ? i am using react for the frontend. I would appreciate any help.
I tried different options with vimeo player

I see on the documentation you can achieve it via iframe by passing the video like that:  , per this documentation https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/12426260232977-Player-parameters-overview although if you don't do it on back-end any user accustomed enough with javascript can totally re-enable the speed option. this is a disadvantage i suppose this method has.

You can hide the controls, but I am not sure if that will prevent all possible ways of fast forwarding / jumping to a specific time. I don't see any other options, that could facilitate what you want. (And I can't see why the provider of such a video hosting service would have any interest in offering such an option to begin with.)

I was able to figure it out. if anyone is struggling with the same issue, please comment and I will share with you the code.

I recommend to creaste an answer post to share the solution you found. Also, I do not understand why you want to prevent fast forwarding. Whether the use normal speed or fast speed while they ignore the video is irrelevant, isn't it? I assume you want to make sure that the users actually watch the video and at least remember part of it afterwards. The solution for that is more than preventing fast forward. Let me know whether I understood your goal or not.
